# Is this the correct way to evaluate the limit of this function?

Tags: limits

I need to compute the limit of $10xe^{1/x} - 10x$ as $x$ approaches infinity. Since $e^{1/x}$ approaches 1 as x approaches infinity, shouldn't the expression approach 0? I also tried doing this using l'hopital's rule but couldn't arrive at the correct answer, which is 10. Any help or hints would be appreciated.

Comment: how small is $e^{1/x} - 1?$

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: The exponential function has a Taylor series. By writing just the first few terms, you can get a very good approximation for $e^{1/x} - 1.$

Comment: $\infty \cdot 0$ is an indeterminant form, you cannot say that the limit approaches $0$ because $e^{\frac{1}{x}} - 1 \to 0$

Comment: I am not familiar with the Taylor series

Comment: ok I got the right answer using l'hopital's rule but is there any way to do this without using l'hopital's rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that $e^{1/x}$ approaches $1$ as $x\to\infty$ tempts us to believe that the limit is zero. But we should never rely on such hand-wavy arguments. The issue is that $e^{1/x}$ approaches one, while at the same time $10x$ approaches infinity. It is difficult to say exactly what the limit is. Your are also right that we need to use L'Hopital's rule. But L'Hopital's rule needs a fraction. So we rewrite the limit as $$\lim_{x\to\infty} 10xe^{1/x}-10x=\lim_{x\to\infty}10x(e^{1/x}-1)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^{1/x}-1}{\frac{1}{10x}}.$$
The limit of both numerator and denominator is $0$. So we attempt to apply L'Hopital's rule. In doing so, we get
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{-e^{1/x}/x^2}{-1/10x^2}=\lim_{x\to\infty} 10e^{1/x}=10.$$
So indeed, our intuition has failed us! Good thing we have L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: I think your first sentence is misleading and misses the opportunity to do some teaching: the fact that $e^{1/x}-1\to0$ does *not* "suggest" the limit is zero, because this expression is multiplied by $x$. This is like saying the fact that $1+1/x\to1$ "suggests" $(1+1/x)^x\to1$. What the OP is missing is that $x$ gets big precisely as $e^{1/x}$ gets close to 1, so in fact it is not so easy to predict what the limit will be (without a closer look at the relative rates).

Comment: You are right. I will make an edit.

Answer (score 2):

As $x$ goes to infinity,
$$ e^{1/x} = 1 + \frac{1}{x}  + \frac{1}{2x^2}  + \frac{1}{6x^3} + smaller  $$
$$ e^{1/x} -1=  \frac{1}{x}  + \frac{1}{2x^2}  + \frac{1}{6x^3} + smaller  $$
$$ 10x(e^{1/x} -1)= 10    + \frac{5}{x}  + \frac{5}{3x^2} + smaller  $$

Answer (score 0):

without L'Hopitals rule:

factor out the $10x.$

$y = 1/x$  You don't have to actually make this substitution.  But, when you have limits going to infinity, you can take the reciprocal and find the limit as it goes to 0.

$\lim_\limits{y\to 0} 10 \dfrac{(e^y - 1)}{y}$

Now you might recognise this from the derivation of the derivative of $e^x$

$\frac{d}{dx} e^x = \lim_\limits{h\to 0}  \dfrac{(e^{x+h} - e^x)}{h}= \lim_\limits{h\to 0}  \dfrac{e^x(e^{h} - 1)}{h} = e^x$

If that is too hand-wavy...

$e^y = \lim_\limits{n\to \infty} (1 + \frac{y}{n})^n = 1 + \frac{n y}{n} + \frac{(n)(n-1) y^2}{2n^2}... $

$\dfrac{e^y -1}{y} = 1 + \dfrac{(n-1) y}{2n} + \dfrac{(n-1)(n-2) y^2}{6n^2}...$

And as $y$ goes to $0$, $\dfrac{e^y -1}{y}$ goes to 1.

10